# I want output in specified format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arraylist, echarts

I am trying to create timeline map using echarts js. I hope I am not able to figure out how to create 'optiosn' as required. Using these code, I obtained 'option' as picture below.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const data = []
const date= []
let options= []

axios.get('https://data.nepalcorona.info/api/v1/covid').then((res) => {
  const array = res.data
  const groups = array.reduce((groups, info) =>{
    const date = info.reportedOn;
    if (!groups[date]) {
      groups[date] = [];
    }
    groups[date].push(info);
    return groups;
  }, {});
  const groupingDate = Object.keys(groups).map((date) =>{
    return{
      date: date,
      infos: groups[date]
    };

  })
  const sortedData = groupingDate.sort((a,b) => {
    var dateA = new Date(a.date) , dateB = new Date(b.date)
    return  dateA - dateB
  })
  for(let i=0; i< sortedData.length; i++) {
    date.push(sortedData[i].date)
    const array = sortedData[i].infos
    data.push(array)
  }
  const points= [];
  const newlist = data.map(x => {
    points.push([x[0].point.coordinates[0], x[0].point.coordinates[1], x[0].age]);
    return {
      series:{
        data: points.slice(0)
      }
    }
  })
  options.push(newlist)
  console.log(options)
})
```

```
export default {
...
options: [options][0],
...
}
```

The result of this is obtained as below:
[image: Result obtained]

But i dont want an unnecessary array as it is obtained. I want options as below:

options: Object
---baseOption: Object
**---options: Array[67]**

I hope you can understand what i am saying.

Comment: try `export default {
...
options: options,
...
}`

Comment: "TypeError: componentType.split is not a function"...... This is the error i get by keeping options: options. I should pass object so i have tried keeping options: [options] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the spread operator in your third last line as following

```
options.push(...newlist)
```

instead of

```
options.push(newlist)
```